# smartgwt ListGridRecord having boolean field issue

Tags: smartgwt

i am using ListGrid of SmartGwt api. and there is boolean field type in my listgrid( which is shown as CheckBox on UI). i want to make it uneditable on single selection on record.

to make my thing clear, check this http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_editing_modal. boolean field is uneditable uneditable on single click event. but as i am doing the same in my project. this thing is not happening. how would i do it? thanks in Advance.

Comment: After trying on the showcase, the boolean field seems to be "editable" any time...;

Comment: sorry it was mozilla bug. therefore i was not able to edit checkbox on single click. but the problem for me still exist. i want to make it uneditable on single click itself. how would i do it. pls help me guys.

Comment: Can you specify when do you want it to be editable & when to be uneditable?

Comment: i want checkbox field to be uneditable on single click and editable only on double click on ListGridRecord. so how would i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ok to display true/false or something of your choice instead of checkbox in non-edit mode, you can use a CellFormatter for particular field of ListGrid.

```
    //"attributeName" is listgridfield's name
    listGrid.getField("attributeName").setCellFormatter(new CellFormatter() {

          @Override
          public String format(Object value, ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
            if (value != null) {
              return String.valueOf(value);
            }
            return "false";
          }
        });
```

If listgridfield record value is true,true will be displyed otherwise false.In edit mode it will again appear as checkbox

**UPDATE**

The property of ListGridField which allowes to edit a boolean field without entring inline edit mode is **canToggle**.
So try

```
listGridField.setCanToggle(false);
```

Comment: thanks @aruns but i want to display the boolean value in checkbox only. so i have to do it that way

Comment: hey @aruns.....but i am using DataSourceField with ListGridRecord to populate data in ListGrid...so is there any way around with this ?

Comment: are you saying that u have not added any listGridField to ListGrid.But you have added only datasource to listgrid like listGrid.addDataSource(dataSource)

Comment: yes @aruns, i have not used any ListGridField to populate data in ListGrid....but i have added DataSource to listGrid using listGrid.addDataSource(dataSource) and used Record to DataSource through the method DataSource.addData(record) to populate my ListGrid.

Comment: after the line listGrid.addDataSource(dataSource) insert listGrid.getField("datasourceFieldName").setCanToggle(false);

Comment: hey @aruns yes my problem is solved now. thanks a TON.... u helped me a lot...gratitude for you replies and helping me a lot... :)